# Can I use eureka server in cluster mode in data centers other than cloud environment

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am using eureka server as a service registry to my micro service architecture.  I want to configure eureka server to be in cluster mode to make use of high availability and fault tolerance. I would like to know does eureka server will run in cluster mode in non cloud environment data centers

Comment: eureka server will run in cluster mode on any two machines, as long as they can find each other through the network.

Comment: Thanks for you response @IndraneelBende

Comment: You can even run it in cluster mode on one machine(host) by changing the etc/hosts file

Comment: Sure.. i will try that. Thank you @IndraneelBende